# error from laravel's foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Getting error message from Laravel's foreach loop:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

My foreach loop is :

```
@foreach ($task as $tasks)

    <td>{{$tasks->name}}</td>

@endforeach
```

My controller is:

```
public function show($id){
    $task = Task::find($id);

    return view('tasks.show')->withTask($task);
;
}
```

Comment: Umm off-topic maybe but why do you have that extra semicolon inside you Controller? On-topic is your `$task` **traversable**? `dd($task)` before the foreach inside blade.

Comment: @Mihailo that was not off-topic mate.

Comment: @linuxartisan's answer is correct. You cannot expect to receive a collection from `$task = Task::find($id);`. It just returns the matching `Task` object

Comment: @steven If you have resolved this problem, please accept the answer that helped you; so that the question doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 2):

You are giving a wrong data type to the `foreach` loop.

A `foreach` requires an `array` or a `Collection`.

The statement

```
$task = Task::find($id);
```

will give you a `Task` model (not a `Collection`).
Hence you cannot iterate over it.

Also, since you are trying to display the `Task` resource (assuming this as you are calling the controller's `show()` function), you don't need to iterate over the model - as you will be displaying a single entity's attributes.

---

Just do this

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id){
    $task = Task::find($id);

    return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
}
```

**In the view:**

```
Name: {{ $task->name }}
// other attributes here
```

Answer (score 1):

I Never seen to set variable like you, try this

```
 return view('tasks.show')->with('task', $task);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the foreach variables

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
   <td> {{ $task->name }} </td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. This will solve your problem

Your Controller

```
public function show($id){
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
}
```

As it gets only one value so no need to use foreach. You should write this

```
<td>{{$tasks->name}}</td>
```

The findOrFail method return only one value. So No need to loop it. 
Hopefully this will solve your problem.